# Is there a way terminate host and device program execution if a CUDA thread encounters an error?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm new to CUDA programming.  In serial code I often have a function that I use for gracefully exiting code after an error occurs. E.g.

```
void exit_with_error(char * message){
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", message);
  fflush(stderr);
  exit(1);
}
```

QUESTION : Is there a clean way to do that in the device code using CUDA 8.0?

I'm looking for something similar to what you can do in [MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818740/gracefully-exit-with-mpi).  So if one thread on the GPU device encounters an 'error' (e.g. a conditional that should never be true), it

1. prints the error
2. sends a signal to all other threads to exit (possibly flushing their stdout/stderr buffers).
3. program terminates.

Comment: you want this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api

Comment: No. That is used in the host code.  I want a way to force program termination if a single thread encounters a condition that I think should never happen. E.g. `if(A>B){exit_program_now()}`

Comment: Not sure if in newer versions is possible, it was not in 2011: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114449/cuda-how-to-assert-in-kernel-code

Comment: its not possible.  Termination of a host thread must be accomplished by host code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  CUDA device code cannot cause termination of a host thread or process.

Termination of a host thread must be accomplished by host code.